# Getting Started with Rails section 5.8 - SyntaxError in ArticlesController#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm doing [the tutorial for RoR](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) and am getting an exception:

> SyntaxError in ArticlesController#index
>
> "....rails/blog/app/views/articles/index.html.erb:18: syntax error,
>   unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input ensure ^"

It points to line 18 of an 16 line file. index.html.erb:

```
<h1>Listing articles</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Text</th>
  </tr>

  <% @articles.each.do |article| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= article.title %></td>
      <td><%= article.text %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', article_path(article) %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

The articles_controller.rb file:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    @article.save
    redirect_to @article
  end

  private
    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
    end

end
```

Not sure where my error is. I'm using LightTable to edit the work.

Comment: `@articles.each.do |article|` should probably be `@articles.each do |article|`

Comment: Thank you! rusty debugging....

Answer (score -1):

In Ruby `do` is a keyword that denotes a block. Not a method.

```
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= article.title %></td>
    <td><%= article.text %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', article_path(article) %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Additionally you are not properly checking if the article is valid in your `create` method:

```
def create
  @article = Article.new(article_params)
  if @article.save
    redirect_to @article
  else
    render :new # renders /app/views/articles/new.html.erb
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you! rusty debugging. The next section of the lesson adds the debugging and links. Much appreciated!

Answer (score -2):

You have a typo on your code, it should be `<% @articles.each do |article| %>`

```
<h1>Listing articles</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Text</th>
  </tr>

  <% @articles.each do |article| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= article.title %></td>
      <td><%= article.text %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', article_path(article) %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```